# ImageView setImageBitmap not updating after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rotation, imageview

I'm working on a simple android app that downloads images in a separate thread and then updates imageViews in the main activity. It works perfectly, however when I rotate the screen while it's downloading, the imageView no longer updates with the image.

This is what the code looks like in the UI thread that updates the imageViews:

```
public void setImage(Bitmap bat, int view) {

    Log.d("main", pic1.getDrawable().toString());

    switch (view) {
    case 1:

        Log.d("main", bat.toString());

        pic1.setImageBitmap(bat);

        Log.d("main", pic1.getDrawable().toString());

        break;
    case 2:
        pic2.setImageBitmap(bat);
        break;
    }
```

I put in the log to try to debug this. It works when I download without rotating. When I do rotate my log tells me this:

```
07-30 03:29:59.380: D/main(3658): android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@42357908
07-30 03:29:59.390: D/main(3658): android.graphics.Bitmap@423af618
07-30 03:29:59.390: D/main(3658): android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@423afb20
```

So obviously the imageView drawable is changing, however, the screen stays the same. I thought perhaps trying tofind the imageView again with `(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` inside of this method so that I can be sure the correct imageView is being referenced even after the rotation of the screen, but it did not make a difference.

Why isn't the image updating on my screen?

Comment: where are you calling this setImage() method?

Comment: your activity is recreated or you are managing the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

```
Why isn't the image updating on my screen?
```

First of all you are still downloading that image while you are rotating it, behind the scene what it is doing is that when you are rotating your screen a you are recreating the activity and it should destroy the previous one but since you still have a reference of the ImageView by the time the downloading is done it will update the imageView from the last Activity not in the new recreated activity.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is the issue, but I can't seem to find a way around it.

Comment: @JoeBruzek either prevent it from screen orientation or redownload the image again when new activity is recreated

Answer (score 0):

Check are you getting same response while orientation changes or without orientation changes?

If yes, then use global variable (bitmap) for storing downloaded image using asynctask. Then inside

```
       "onConfigurationChanged(..)"
```

set that downloaded image to your

```
        ImageView.
```

This will surely solve your problem.